# How do I link to another html with a different style? Is it possible to do?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a home page that links to several of my projects. I am trying to link to another html that has a different style than the home page. The images and text I have for the second html works fine, but it takes on the style of the home page, and not its own design which is different. My question is is it possible to link to another html that has a different style? If so, how do I input this? When I try putting the style for the second html in the home page's folder, it won't let me since there's already another style.css I used for the main home page. I tried changing the name of the second style file and it still does not work.

Comment: You should include some code to illustrate what you are doing. It's unclear what you mean by "link to". That could mean so many things without seeing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have two HTML pages and you want a different CSS style for each page.

You can have several CSS files but you cannot have two with the same name.

1. Create two different CSS files. For example home.css and secondpage.css
2. Create two different HTML files. For example home.html and secondpage.html
3. Go to the `<head>` of home.html and add `<link href="home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`
4. Go to the `<head>` of secondpage.html and add `<link href="secondpage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Make sure the html files and css files are in the same folder.
If you have trouble finding the `<head>`, see the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use different style for diffrent html pages. There are mainly two easy way

1. Either you use different css files for each html page (Which is not recommended):
   Let say for homepage.html you use mystyle.css

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
   </head>
   </html>
   ```

   So for other html page you can use secondpage.css

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="secondpage.css">
   </head>
   </html>
   ```

   and make sure you specify path correctly
2. Other way which is recommended is you give diffrent class name for the html attributes, So that you can specify the all styling in single stylesheet. which will reduce your page loding time too.

Lets say this is home.html :

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="homepage">
    // Other content here
    </div

    </body>
    </html>
```

So in Second html file you can use different class

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="secondpage">
    // Other content here
    </div

    </body>
    </html>
```

so now yourstylesheet will look like :

```
.homepage{
        //your style here
        }
.secondpage{
          // your style here
         }
```

Hope so this helps.